# Unable to scrape the data using bs4

Tags: web-scraping, beautifulsoup, tripadvisor

I am trying to scrape the star rating for the "value" data from the Trip Advisor hotels but I am not able to get the data using class name:
Below is the code which I have tried to use:

```
review_pages=requests.get("https://www.tripadvisor.com/Hotel_Review-g60745-d94367-Reviews-Harborside_Inn-Boston_Massachusetts.html")  
soup3=BeautifulSoup(review_pages.text,'html.parser')   
value=soup3.find_all(class_='hotels-review-list-parts-AdditionalRatings__bubbleRating--2WcwT')    
Value_1=soup3.find_all(class_="hotels-review-list-parts-AdditionalRatings__ratings--3MtoD")
```

When I am trying to capture the values it is returning an empty list. Any direction would be really helpful. I have tried mutiple class names which are in that page but I am getting various fields such as Data,reviews ect but I am not able to get the bubble ratings for only service.

Answer (score 1):

You can use an attribute = value selector and pass the class in with its value as a substring with ^ starts with operator to allow for different star values which form part of the attribute value.

Or, more simply use the `span` type selector to select for the child spans.

```
.hotels-hotel-review-about-with-photos-Reviews__subratings--3DGjN span
```

In this line:

```
values=soup3.select('.hotels-hotel-review-about-with-photos-Reviews__subratings--3DGjN [class^="ui_bubble_rating bubble_"]')
```

The first part of the selector, when reading from left to right, is selecting for the parent class of those ratings. The following space is a descendant combinator combining the following attribute = value selector which gathers a list of the qualifying children. As mentioned, you can replace that with just using span.

Code:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import re

review_pages=requests.get("https://www.tripadvisor.com/Hotel_Review-g60745-d94367-Reviews-Harborside_Inn-Boston_Massachusetts.html")  
soup3=BeautifulSoup(review_pages.content,'lxml')   
values=soup3.select('.hotels-hotel-review-about-with-photos-Reviews__subratings--3DGjN [class^="ui_bubble_rating bubble_"]')    #.hotels-hotel-review-about-with-photos-Reviews__subratings--3DGjN span
Value_1 = values[-1]
print(Value_1['class'][1])
stars = re.search(r'\d', Value_1['class'][1]).group(0)
print(stars)
```

Although I use re, I think it is overkill and you could simply use replace.